# gradle: best way to encapsulate custom dsl

Tags: java, groovy, gradle, encapsulation

[my screencast](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B08GAyjqgToLVlR3T3ZBVW1mRU0&usp=sharing), i hope my aExtFunc can work in build.gradle in any projects, but intellij idea raise

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'gradleExt'
```

**my question is:** how to fix it.

Comment: while a screencast seem convenient it is not a good medium for SO.  Please formulate your problem as text and put your code and exceptions etc here.  The question as it is can not stand on it's own and relies on data on some google thingy, which might go away any time.

Answer (score 0):

Defining dependency on the project

```
dependencies{
  compile project(':gradleExt')
}
```

Doesn't mean that you can work with the content of the project in your build script:

```
task ATask() {
  new gradleExt.Ext().aExtFunc()
}
```

You probably need to create new groovy class directly in the `build.gradle` file implementing desired behaviour. Or if you really want to have the implementation in different place you need to add the classpath dependecy into the `buildScript{}` block. See the documentation on implementing custom tasks:

> http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html

If you want custom dsl, then *custom gradle plugin* is probably what you are looking for

> http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html

And also please double check the documentation on *multi-project builds* if that might be of any use to you, it is not clear from the "*my screencast*" what your overall gradle setup is. I would post the link, but I don't have enough reputation.